# Convert images, text, CSV files, MS office doc to PDF and merge it to single PDF

Tags: pdf, itext

Need to convert different file types (different images types, text files (csv, txt), MS office documents (docx, xlsx) into Pdf and merge them into single PDF at the end. 
Can iText be used for this? if Yes, is iText core enough or do I need any additional iText modules/plug-in for Java?

Comment: iText alone cannot convert MS Office documents to PDF. You need other software to first convert the MS Office to HTML (MS Office itself can save to HTML), and then iText can convert HTML to PDF. You need iText 7 Core + the add-on pdfHTML to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For the image-based stuff, it for sure can be used for that. For the file type conversions, you'll likely need some additional libraries outside of iText.

Check out - https://www.baeldung.com/pdf-conversions-java

There are several examples there on converting files to/from PDF